# Symfony logger failing to write in a log file

Tags: symfony, logging, callback, twilio, monolog

I'm using Symfony 5 with API platform, docker-compose and Twilio and I'm using the SMS messaging feature.

So in my Twilio console, on SMS callback I put my route that I've open with ngrok : `https://f64560c9efff.ngrok.io/twilio/intervention/request/response`

To see the content of Twilio's response I wanted to implement a logger

so I installed monolog and implemented the conf file `packages/dev/monolog.yaml` :

```
monolog:
    channels: ['twilio']
    handlers:
        main:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
            channels: ["!event"]
        # uncomment to get logging in your browser
        # you may have to allow bigger header sizes in your Web server configuration
        #firephp:
        #    type: firephp
        #    level: info
        #chromephp:
        #    type: chromephp
        #    level: info
        console:
            type: console
            process_psr_3_messages: false
            channels: ["!event", "!doctrine", "!console"]
        twilio:
            type: stream
            path: '%kernel.logs_dir%/twilio.log'
            channels: [ 'twilio' ]
```

I've created a `twilio.log` file in `api/var/log/` with `chmod 777` to test

In my controller I'm doing :

```
    private $em;
    private $twilioLogger;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em,LoggerInterface $twilioLogger)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->twilioLogger = $twilioLogger;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/twilio/route", name="twilio_route")
     */
    public function twilioRoute(Request $request): Response
    {
        $answer = new Answer();
        $answer->setResponse($request->getContent());
        $answer->setResponseAt(new DateTimeImmutable());

        $this->twilioLogger->info("WE PASS HERE");
        $this->twilioLogger->info($request->getContent());

        $this->em->persist($answer);
        $this->em->flush();

        return new Response(Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
```

So I know Twilio's callback went through cause an object `Answer` with only the `responseAt` field have been persisted

But my `twilio.log` file is empty and I am not understanding why the logger is not writting in it

Do I miss a piece of configuration or am I missing something ?

If anyone have an idea or leads I'll appreciate it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't do anything different to what you did. However, one thing did stand out:

> I've created a twilio.log file in api/var/log/

Log files, by default, are created in `var/log` not in `api/var/log`. When I mocked up a quick example, the file was created for me and contained the relevant log messages. I hope that this helps.